# linux | Найти (вывести) все пищущие приводы

Tags: linux, shell, устройства, bash, perl

Добрый день,

Каким образом можно вывести список оптических приводов? Интересует штатные средства имеющиеся в большинстве систем (а-ля udev и пр., не возбраняются решения на perl - хотя и не представляю, что это может быть))).

p.s. знаю о wodim --devices , но требовать наличия wodim лишь для сканирования наличия устройства глупо. Нужен менее зависимое решение.

p.p.s. парсить содержимое /proc/scsi/scsi на премет type=cd-rom тоже не есть гуд, как мне кажется ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а как насчет `cat /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/info`?

Comment: гуд.. уже неплохо) посмотрим, что еще предложат

Answer (score 1):

На все случаи жизни

```
dmesg | egrep --color  -i 'cdrom|dvd|cd/rw|writer'
```

Дополню тем что можно посмотреть с имеющейся udev базой. Не айс как удобно конечно.

> udevadm info -a -n /dev/sr0

Файл sr0  можно получить, прочитав файл правил в каталоге rules.d. Там много исчерпывающей информации.

Comment: разницу видите? ))    bdstore@bdstore:/proc$ dmesg | grep -i 'cdrom|dvd|cd/rw|writer|bd-rw'    bdstore@bdstore:/proc$ wodim --devices    wodim: Overview of accessible drives (3 found) :    -------------------------------------------------------------------------    0  dev='/dev/sg1'      rwrwrw : 'PIONEER' 'BD-RW   BDR-206'    1  dev='/dev/sg2'      rwrwrw : 'PIONEER' 'BD-RW   BDR-206'    2  dev='/dev/sg4'      rwrwrw : 'PIONEER' 'BD-RW   BDR-207'    -------------------------------------------------------------------------хотя конечно можно добавить еще

Comment: а я вопщето написал egrep  а не grep.

Comment: А какая разница в данном случае )) Это расширяет возможности поиска? )))    bdstore@bdstore:/proc$ dmesg | egrep --color  -i 'cdrom|dvd|cd/rw|writer'    [194280.697956] cdrom: This disc doesn't have any tracks I recognize!    [430979.835075] cdrom: This disc doesn't have any tracks I recognize!    [449336.922471] cdrom: This disc doesn't have any tracks I recognize!    [1916030.256189] cdrom: This disc doesn't have any tracks I recognize!

Comment: В вашем конкретном случае, нет, а вообще да.